# Performing action upon completion of Android Calendar intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-calendar-api

I am calling the following function to add a Calendar event (taken largely from [roman10](http://www.roman10.net/)):

```
private void addEvent() {
    Intent l_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    l_intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    l_intent.putExtra("title", "roman10 calendar tutorial test");
    l_intent.putExtra("description", "This is a simple test for calendar api");
    l_intent.putExtra("eventLocation", "@home");
    l_intent.putExtra("beginTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
    l_intent.putExtra("endTime", System.currentTimeMillis() + 1800*1000);
    l_intent.putExtra("allDay", 0);
    l_intent.putExtra("eventStatus", 1);
    l_intent.putExtra("visibility", 0);
    l_intent.putExtra("transparency", 0);
    l_intent.putExtra("hasAlarm", 1);

    try {
        startActivity(l_intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, no compatible calendar is found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

After the completion of this intent, I would like to manually refresh my list activity, which simply holds a list of all the user's events (I want it to instantly reflect the changes). Does anyone know of a way to do this? Is there any particular function which is called upon the completion of this intent that I can modify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to use startActivityForResults(Intent, id)

```
static private final int CALENDAR_DONE 101;
startActivityForResults(l_intent, CALENDAR_DONE);
```

Then add this function to your activity:

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (reqCode) {
      case (CALENDAR_DONE) :
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          //Do stuff here
        }       
      break;
    }
  }
```